# Why does map api vender require api key?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to build an application based on map navigation. After some searching I found that all the map api providers require register a app key in order to use their API. I wander why they want a key. Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons to include key.

The maps APIs are resource heavy and they require lot of computation and database calls before a response can be send to client.

Main reasons can be:

- To authorize the client or agent.
- To track the number of calls a particular client makes.
- To monitor unwanted behaviour.
- Help API provider in billing.
- To avoid unauthorized use by any party other than intended.
- Overcome the use and issues of public Username/Password.
- Allow multiple devices to access the API.

...and many more reasons

**More reading:** 
[Top Six Reasons to Use API Keys](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/why-do-apis-use-api-keys-instead-of-usernames)

[Why do APIs use API Keys instead of Usernames?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32910/why-do-apis-use-api-keys-instead-of-usernames/)